# IntelliJ changes npm pkg import paths on refactor move

Tags: intellij-idea

When I move a file or directory, IntelliJ fixes all relative import paths according to the new path.

Since last update the package imports also get changed, for example:

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import glamorous from 'glamorous';
```

changes to

```
import { fromJS } 'immutable/dist/immutable-nonambient';
import glamorous from 'glamorous/typings/glamorous';
```

I get that the named imports (or lack of) probably match in both cases, but since the imports are absolute it doesn't really make sense to change the import paths.

Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: What IDE version do you use?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-191.7141.44, built on May 7, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.4